# Dependency Injection Scoped resource created multiple times

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

This question is posted to help others (answer posted too).

We have an Azure Functions app which uses Dependency Injection (the Microsoft standard one).

We are seeing a class registered as `Scoped` created multiple times within a single request.

```
public class MyStrategy : IMyStrategy
{
  public MyStrategy(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ISomeRepository someRepository) { ... }
}

public class UnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork
{
  public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) { ... }
}

public class SomeRepository: ISomeRepository
{
  public SomeRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) { ... }
}
```

When `IMyStrategy` is injected we see that the DbContext in `UnitOfWork` is not the same instance as the one in `SomeRepository` - even though all of these are registered using `services.AddScoped`.

For us, this means that new objects added to the `ApplicationDbContext` via `SomeRepository` are not being saved to the DB when `ApplicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync` is called from our `UnitOfWork` (because we are adding to once instance, and calling Save on another).

Answer (score 6):

The problem was arising because the Microsoft extension `AddHttpClient<T1, T1>` for `IServiceCollection` was being used in an Azure Function app.

This is a known problem in the .NET Core 3.1 framework. There is a fix already included in the binaries, but it is hidden behind a feature flag. To fix the problem, add the following setting to your Azure Functions app.

```
"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableEnhancedScopes"
```

Comment: your solution worked for us. Can you elaborate a bit more about how the usage of AddHttpClient<T1, T1> is causing this issue?

Comment: I think it's as simple as it was a bug in the framework that was fixed by MS, but activated via a feature flag because they weren't sure how the code change would affect existing apps and they didn't want to a breaking change in a minor release. I expect the default behaviour was changed in .net 5/6.

Comment: @PeterMorris Hey can you please check my issue mentioned in https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/9316, and please let me know if that can be solved with this EnableEnhancedScopes

Comment: @PrashantAgrawal You can know by trying it.